# How to inspect the element with "edit as html" in gmail message via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, gmail, embed

### Heading ##Currently, I inspect elements in my gmail message, and "edit as HTML". This allows me to embed HTML inside my gmail message.

I am automating the creation of the HTML through a form script and would like to prepare the entire gmail message but I haven't figured out how to -> inspect element -> "edit as html" through javascript.

I made a .gif below showing the current process I use, and when I need to email 5 or 10 different people each their own html that I generate with javascript, is time consuming to have to do it this way.

http://giphy.com/gifs/26tnmCSqjD7ivD5hm

Currently, when I prepare the gmail message, I just see the HTML text in the gmail message. That is why I need to figure out how to "edit as HTML".

Is this possible?

```
var email = document.getElementById('email_address');

var url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&to="+ email.value     + "&su=Subject - &body=<h1>Testing Html inside gmail</h1>&tf=1";

window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Comment: Do you want to insert a message into an email(you're about to send) or edit an existing message? And you want all this to be operated from your site?

Comment: New message. I know how to bring up the gmail compose email with text prefilled, but it is not displaying as HTML. I know in the gmail, when you inspect element you have to specifically select "edit as html" to get the html to display correctly in the gmail message.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: There. It opens new message in gmail, but it doesn't register the HTML.

Comment: That's some security google has added, I don't think it's possible this way(at least, not easily). You could try using [mail](http://www.php.net/mail)

Comment: Hmmm, I just edited the post to show a GIF of how I currently do it, if I could do this with code instead of manually doing it. I haven't tried using the 'mail' link yet as I really want to have this down through JS.